# What is the average length of a line inside the unit square?

Tags: graphics, geometry, probability

This question lies in the chapter exercise of chapter 14 Sampling of book: Fundamentals of Computer Graphics by Peter Shirley and Steve Marschner.

Although this is not mentioned in the question but I assume tur lines are random and are uniformly distributed.

As per my current knowledge the average length here means the expected value of a function f(r, theta) which gives the length of a line (r, theta) (the line is in normal-angle space) inside the unit square [0, 1]×[0, 1]. It is possible to find such function but I am not getting what **probability distribution function** to use in this case.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not suitable for programmer's site - pure math for math.stackexhange.com

Comment: The trick here is to know what 'uniformly distributed' means for lines. You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability) to see some of the issues

Comment: @MBo, sorry, that's my bad, I was unaware of math.stackexchange (I'm new in using these sites) for this stuff. I will post the same question on that too. Thank u for correcting me.